# TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.default) is not a function(…)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Facing this error on one screen. While same redux configuration is working on all other screens.

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.default) is not a function.(In'(0 , _reactRedux.default)(mapStateToProps,{})','(0 , _reactRedux.default)' is undefined)
```

Comment: Ciao, can you post the screen who fails? Just the logic...

Comment: **Thanks** for getting back to this, I just figured it out.

Comment: Happy to ear that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope it helps someone.

Change

```
import connect from "react-redux";
```

to

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
```